# Course on HPC with Python?

Tags: python, hpc

I am developing a simulation and data-processing pipeline in Python. Currently I am still "making it work", but in a few months I will have to "make it fast". I am not very good at HPC in general and particularly not with Python.

What online (or Europe-based) courses are available that contain at least the following topics:

- parallel computation in Python, and
- interfacing Python and C?

*Opinion based part (sorry about this):*
The only course I managed to find is Python Academy in Leipzig (http://www.python-academy.com/courses/python_hpc.html). Has anybody tried Python Academy? I don't find any independent reviews, but there is a significant cost, so I would not want to go in blind.

Comment: Sorry this is off-topic, SO is not a course recommendation site

Comment: You can ask me about it. ;)

Comment: @MikeMüller, thanks for replying. What kind of students do you normally teach on this course?

Comment: Mainly scientists and engineers who do heavy numerical computations. Participants should have solid Python knowledge.  Individual HPC problems may be addressed in the  course if feasibly and of interest for others.

Answer (score 0):

None of the items mentioned in the course description qualifies for HPC; which currently refers to GPU utilization for massive parallelisation.

> **High-performance computing (HPC)** is the use of parallel processing for running advanced application programs efficiently, reliably and
>   quickly. The term applies especially to systems that function above a
>   **teraflop** or *10^12 floating-point operations per second*.

The course contents will enable you to program current generation of Raspberry PI which has a quad core processor and dedicated graphics processor. But I would not call that HPC (High Performance Computing)

If you are interested in High Performance Computing, get a NVIDIA graphics card and try [pycuda](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/) or try [pyopencl](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/) which is a more open standard for hybrid computing.

You can find good Videos on Youtube explaining the both.

Comment: Well, we use `numba` that uses PyCuda to translate to GPU code.

Comment: It seems like `numba` is wrapper which includes many more options; I have not used the same but certainly will look into the same.

Comment: [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/index.html) is is just-in-time  (JIT) compiler  that compiles decorated Python code to [LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/) code, which in turn compiles down to machine code. LLVM supports generation of  multicore programs. Numba can also compile a restricted subset of Python code into CUDA kernels.

Comment: Couse description does cover HPC topics: paralellisation, vectorisation, optimising and interfacing to compiled languages. Are you claiming that HPC is synonymous with using GPGPU in parallel? If so, you are just wrong. You can use GPGPU for HPC but the vast majority of time used on HPC worldwide is on standard CPU cores. Only a small subset of problems are amenable to effient use of GPGPU. (This subset is growing tho.)

Comment: LLVM & JIT have been around for more than 20 years now, none of them is still able to achieve TFLOPS. 

Parallel computing has been there for more than 15 years now, every smartphone ever created had at least two processor. In 2017 it is hard to buy a processor with single core; even raspberry pi has four cores.

So I can do `numba` on raspberry PI with all parallel programming utilising JIT and LLVM, but nobody is going to call it HPC